# ITextSharp image issue in PDF after printing

Tags: image, pdf, itext

I use ITextSharp to print a PDF document. I put a logo (logo of Microsoft as example) on document and it is described perfectly in PDF file.

[image]

But after printing this PDF, I get gray dots accross logo on paper.

[image]

I use a PNG image with transparent background, and my logo is in high resolution as Microsoft logo. Please help how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you check what the 'actual' pixel color is in the transparent part of this PNG? PNG transparency is not a standard PDF option, so it must be emulated somehow -- or (this is what this check is for) bluntly ignored.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can check this? Any program or tool?

Comment: PDF transparency is mimicked by adding the image without transparency and adding a mask image. In other words: one PNG is converted to two different images inside the PDF. You could use iText RUPS to find both images: http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups

Comment: Bruno, thanks for contribution. I installed the program and found boh images. This part is clear for me already. But how I can make pdf to show logo without gray background?